# Swap values in the list in Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at using python. Here is an insert sort I code. The print() shows I swap the values by the comparison. but when I return it, it gives me the original array. I'm wondering where is the bug I made. Is the usage of swapping value like this correct in python?

```
def insert_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i, -1, -1):
            if arr[j] < arr[j-1]:
                arr[j-1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j-1]
                print(arr)
                
    return arr

insert_sort([5,4,3,2,1])
::[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Running your code, the function returns a modified array and its contents is the same as shown by the last print statement.  The result isn't correctly sorted however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling edges of algorithms used to be a real pain when I just started learning programming, and I believe so do you this time.

The two things you need to note here is

- You start "inserting" at the second element, because the first element is always "sorted on its own". So you should change `range(len(arr))` to `range(1, len(arr))` for the outer loop.
- You end with comparing and swapping the *first two elements*, i.e., `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, **not** `arr[0]` and `arr[-1]`. Python interprets negative indices as "counting from the end" so that causes another wave of mess unless handled properly.

  The change here is to end `j` *before* it reaches zero, so `range(i, -1, -1)` should be `range(i, 0, -1)`.

Now your code runs fine after the above two patches.

```py
def insert_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):   # Start i from 1
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):  # End j at 1
            if arr[j] < arr[j-1]:
                arr[j-1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j-1]
                print(arr)
                
    return arr

insert_sort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your well-structured explication about this bug. You are right I need to be more careful about the edge case when I use j-1.

Answer (score 1):

You were so close!  The problem with your code is that your inner loop allows `j` to be `0`.  This means that you'll be comparing `arr[0]` to `arr[-1]`.  This doesn't crash in Python, but doesn't do what you want either, as you're comparing the first value in the array to the last value.  All you need to do is limit the inner loop to stopping at `1`, and your code works fine:

```
def insert_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):  # <- changed "-1" to "0" here
            if arr[j] < arr[j - 1]:
                arr[j - 1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j - 1]
                print(arr)

    return arr

r = insert_sort([5,4,3,2,1])
print("Result:", r)
```

Result:

```
[4, 5, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
[3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I strongly encourage you to get comfortable with a visual debugger and to apply it liberally to your work.  I didn't figure out what was wrong here by totally understanding the code.  Instead, I just put a breakpoint at the comparison line, which is the core of the entire algorithm, and took a look at what the conditions were each time that line is hit.  I immediately saw that `j` had a value of `0`, so the `arr[j - 1]` looked wrong.  I did all of this in under 30 seconds, and again, I didn't have to know anything about the code to spot this problem.

UPDATE: I just saw @iBug's comment that your first outer loop iteration is unnecessary.  I agree.  You should make that change for your code to be the most "correct" and to be a bit more efficient.  Note, however, that the extra loop iteration does no harm.  It is just a degenerate case that does nothing because the inner loop in that case iterates over `range(0, 0, -1)`, which generates an empty sequence.  This is another thing you might catch pretty easily if you stepped through your code in a debugger.  You'd see that the first outer iteration does not hit the `if` statement at all.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's a good call out. The debugger is better for me to check the edge case(which is easier to neglect for me ) like this.